# CSS: two background images with position on one element

Tags: html, css

In my css file i have one rule: two add two background images before and after text element. Before i used two images and all was ok. But now i use sprites: so i need to get area of big image and post it to element (background-position) but i have one trouble: if i set background position: i could not stuck to it position like left center and right center:

`background: url(../images/png/elements.png) no-repeat -5px -152px, url(../images/png/elements.png) no-repeat -5px -104px;`

how could i float first part to left and second to right of the element?

before was:

`background: url(../images/png/mail.png) no-repeat left center, url(../images/png/edit.png) no-repeat right center;`

is it real to do?

also: i use it with `:hover`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that it is not possible to limit the visible area of sprite images unless the size of the element itself is limited.

However, perhaps you could assign the background images to `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements which are positioned to the left/right side of the parent box properly (either by `float` or `absolute` positioning).

So that you could handle the position of each icon interdependently.

For instance:

```css
.box:before, .box:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block; /* or position these elements by floats, etc. */
  width: 48px;           /* for instance */
  height: 48px;          /* for instance */
 }

.box:before {
  background: url(../images/png/elements.png) no-repeat -5px -152px;
}

.box:after {
  background: url(../images/png/elements.png) no-repeat -5px -104px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: could you create fiddle?

Comment: @brabertaser1992 I added a pseudo-code to demonstrate the solution. Hope it helps.

Comment: As my answer is similar (perhaps a bit more generalized) I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jnfsmile/kfm5cm3q/) for example

Answer (score 1):

The `left` and `right` you are using belong to `background-position`. The pixel definitions are overriding them.

You should separate the images to two different elements.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `Shorthand` for this (especially in the position property):
try with something like:

```css
div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 190px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    background: url(http://alt-web.com/Images/CSSSprite.jpg), url(http://alt-web.com/Images/CSSSprite.jpg);
    background-position: left top, right bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

### Edit: Example with pixels, zero and %.

```css
div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 190px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    background-image: url(http://alt-web.com/Images/CSSSprite.jpg), url(http://alt-web.com/Images/CSSSprite.jpg);
    background-position: 0 0, 100% -1215px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: it possible to do with different images, but not with sprite in pixels

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your comment. (it is a question or a statement?)

Comment: @gmo White true but it depends on how the icons are located within the sprite image. This won't work if the icons are placed beside each other within the image.

Comment: @HashemQolami For sure!!... never ever.. no doubt about that. The only sprite that can be used as a background should be the verticals ones (but I assume that if OP is using it, it's because already know it.)

Answer (score -1):

```css
section.homepage.customer {
    background-image: url('/assets/img/homepage/top-left.png'), url('/assets/img/homepage/bottom-right.png');
    background-position: top left, bottom right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 672px;
}
```